# Signing certificate issue

Tags: certificate, cer

I have a certificate (certificate.cer). When I select this certificate from visual studio project properties Signing tab. It generates error "Selected file does not contain a private key you must choose a certificate that contains a private key". Please help in this context.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a certificate with a private key. That is usually the file extension `*.pfx`.